# How do I know which file has been double clicked on Windows in a running background program?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, background-process

I am trying to create an application in C# which will run as a background program and needs to monitor which file is being double-clicked on (opened). Is there a class in the .NET framework which can help me with this?

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in C#. You will need a file system driver (written in C) to detect any application opening any file. This is because processes in any modern OS are isolated and cannot see what other processes are up to.